# Reloj Digital en C# con Hilos

Tags: c#

Tengo este código en c# que ejecuta un reloj digital:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
      Thread hilo;

      public Form1()
      {
           InitializeComponent();
      }

      delegate void TiempoDelegado();

      public void CambiarTiempo()
      {
         if (this.InvokeRequired) 
         {
            TiempoDelegado delegado = new TiempoDelegado(CambiarTiempo);
            this.Invoke(delegado);
         }
         else
         {
            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00") + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00") + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("00");
         }
      }

      private void Tiempo()
      {
          Thread.Sleep(100);
          CambiarTiempo();
          Tiempo();
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          hilo = new Thread(Tiempo);
          hilo.Start();
      }
  }
```

Si ejecuta bien el reloj pero cuando quiero cerrar la aplicación me marca este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo solucionar esto??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma muy facil de solucionar el problema seria controlar la excepción de `ObjectDisposedException` en el `Invoke`

El código quedaría así:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread hilo;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    delegate void TiempoDelegado();

    public void CambiarTiempo()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            TiempoDelegado delegado = new TiempoDelegado(CambiarTiempo);
            try
            {
                this.Invoke(delegado);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00") + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00") + ":" +
                          DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("00");
        }
    }

    private void Tiempo()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        if (this.Disposing || this.IsDisposed)
            return;
        CambiarTiempo();
        Tiempo();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hilo = new Thread(Tiempo);
        hilo.Start();
    }
}
```

Un saludo,

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

1)  Instalas en nuget el paquete Reactive Extensions (la última version 3.x, no la 4)

2) Importas los siguientes namespaces:

```
using System.Theading;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
```

3) Agregas un campo privado así:

```
private IDisposable timer;
```

4) En el constructor del formulario, después de llamar al método de inicialización, pones esto:

```
timer = Observable
    .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) // crea un timer observable, que está emitiendo eventos cada segundo
    .Select(_ => DateTime.Today.ToShortTimeString()) // obtenemos la hora y la formateamos como texto
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current) // pasamos el evento al hilo principal de la ui
    .Subscribe(dateText => label1.Text = dateText); // el texto con la hora lo asignamos al label
```

5) Y por último, para que el timer no quede "activo" al hacerse el dispose del formulario y te marque error, mueve el método "Dispose" que está en el código generado por el form designer y ponlo en tu code behind, y lo modificas así:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    if (disposing && timer != null)
    { 
        timer.Dispose();
        timer = null;
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Con eso te evitas delegados y timers y todo eso, menos líneas de código, todo está en un solo lugar, etc.